# Make clicking “Recommend Deletion” in the VLQ queue automatically upvote the correct comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, review, low-quality-posts, comment-voting

When I select “Recommend deletion” in the VLQ queue, it will automatically add a comment to the post with my reason, if someone hasn’t already. I’m suggesting that the system automatically upvote the comment on my behalf to indicate that multiple users agree with the comment.